# How to download "secured" flash movie

Tags: firefox, flash

I want to download a movie which is played by flash: [jfk-1963](http://www.jfklibrary.org/Asset-Viewer/Archives/USG-2B-1.aspx)

It is in Public Domain but I am not able to download the source file. I already tried

- Firebug
- Downloadhelper
- file2hd.com

with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark allows you to look directly in the network packages. [youtu.be/8PuUnQCS7DQ](http://youtu.be/8PuUnQCS7DQ)

- search for the "Handshake"-package
- get the content of this package (They contain the rtmp-data)
- use rtmpdump to get the stream:

`rtmpdump -r "rtmp://195.95.193.27/ondemand?_fcs_vhost=cp76677.edgefcs.net:1935" -y "mp4:s/ZsZzRlOTpDOcLzXSWvMhv10uoykcOaCh/DOcJ-FxaFrRg4gtDEwOnVhOjBrO_9PjD" | vlc -` should work

Comment: how does this help?

Comment: I updated my answer on my question

Comment: thanks.  obviously, the more detail in an answer (or question) is always more helpful.